# Teradata - Date format conversion from INT(yyyymmdd) type to date(mm/dd/yyyy) in Teradata SQL Assistant

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I have dates in integer format in a column. The length is 11.
Example values
current format integer (11) --> date format required

- yyyymmdd --> dd/mm/yyyy
- 20121203 --> 03/12/2012
- 20090403 --> 03/04/2009

Can someone suggest a solution keeping in mind that the change need to reflect across the entire column in the table?

Comment: Why don't you use proper date data type?

Comment: Those dates are ambiguous. Depending on your place of origin you might right the first example (`03/12/2012`) as either March 12th or December 3rd.

Comment: you should be using the proper data format and then eventually use DATE_FORMAT to show the date in a local format

Comment: Apologies for the ambiguity in asking the question, I have corrected it now. I am extracting the information (which is stored in int format) from a database and need a proper date format for reporting purposes.

Comment: *dates in integer format* What's the actual datatype, VarChar or Int?

Comment: The actual type is int with length as 11.

Answer (score 0):

Use [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) :

```
select STR_TO_DATE(col1, "%Y%m%d") as my_date
from test_tbl;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> my_date
> 2012-12-03
> 2009-04-03
> ```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b3ed9a138b28b1f055ab292605324438)

Or [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) as previous answer:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(col1, "%d/%m/%Y") as my_date
from test_tbl;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> my_date
> 03/12/2012
> 03/04/2009
> ```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=02de935529d28e4a5c39dd79efae3029)

Maybe using both:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(col1, "%Y%m%d"),'%d/%m/%Y') as my_date
from test_tbl;

my_date
03/12/2012
03/04/2009
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3c49d81471822d6b3b058088cae550f7)

Comment: Thank you very much for your input, I tried this in Teradata but it didn't work, it's giving me an error saying col1 does not match defined type name. error (3706). I think it'll differ in Teradata.

Comment: Why do you tag `mysql` if you're using Teradata?

Comment: I am sorry, didn't know there's a difference, I am quite an amateur with coding stuff, I use teradata for reporting purpose and need the data in a specific format from those tables. I'll remove mySQL tag.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is based on Teradata's storage of dates:

```
Cast(intdate - 19000000 AS DATE)
```

Of course this only works if there are no bad dates, as your source seems to be MySQL there might be 20220200, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For Teradata SQL Assistant, you can use TO_CHAR and then CAST it to a DATE format like this:

```
SEL CAST(TO_CHAR(20211015) AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD')
```

Result: 10/15/2021 (mm/dd/yyyy)

Answer (score -1):

Docummentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

```
DATE_FORMAT("20121203", "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Comment: I am not able to follow this suggestion, can you please help me on how to draft this query for a column in the table.

Comment: @NamanSinghal `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(columnName, "%d/%m/%Y") FROM tableName`